# Ensure date is in ISO 8601 format including offset

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, iso8601

Our API has some PUT/POST methods that accept dates in the body of the request. We have been using ISO 8601 format so far, but we need to make the time offset part mandatory, so the format is exactly: `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss+HH:mm`

`DateTime.ParseExact(...)` doesn't seem to have a format for the time offset portion, only the `"K"` custom format specifier, which doesn't seem to do what we need, and specifying the `HH:mm` twice, as above, doesn't work either.

Is there another way to get .NET to require a date to be in exactly the format above, or do I need to use regex's or something else?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#zzzSpecifier

Comment: @trailmax Some of the offsets are off by 30 minutes.  Scroll down a bit in the wiki page.

Comment: @Amy so it is - I've missed that in the list. DUH!

Comment: @Amy thanks, that works - 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz' to be exact